# Is there a simulator in which you can test your own helicopter model?

Tags: simulators, helicopters

I am currently trying to make a model helicopter. I have calculated lift generated by the blades and upward acceleration of the helicopter. However, I amn't very sure if my helicopter will fly or not. Is there a simulator in which you can test your ***own*** helicopter model? (It would be very nice of you if you could suggest a simulator that is compatible with a Mac).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[RC Desk Pilot](https://www.rcdeskpilot.com/) is a simple, free, open source RC simulator that has an aircraft editor where you can create your own models, or modify an existing model.

If you really want to get into this, [X-Plane](https://www.x-plane.com/) is a popular open source simulator for full-size aircraft. It's super detailed. Just looking though the overview of the  [plane design tool](https://developer.x-plane.com/manuals/planemaker/) is quite daunting!

Comment: Is it possible for you to list out similar ones, which are compatible with a Mac?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know anything about macs, but as far as I know all simulators have some way of importing additional models, even if they are just text files that you can edit.

Answer (score 3):

A quick search does not show anything on the Mac except maybe some games.

Instead of a program built for a Mac how about an emulator instead?
[Wine](https://wiki.winehq.org/Git_Wine_Tutorial) provides a compatibility layer to run Windows software on MacOS.

A second option would be to install [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org) and then install a copy of Windows as a VM. This may be less performant since it only uses part of the processor / memory.